# Facebook API : Can we know the number of likes, posts, shares, comments individually?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can we know per daily basis through the Facebook API the number of likes, the number comments, the number of shares on our posts and the number of posts made by users to ourg page? Not a sum of all these but each one separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FQL to query the insights data for your app or page. See [documentation and list of available metrics](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/).

`page_fan_adds` will give you the new fans per day, for a page (`application_like_adds` for apps). `page_like_adds`, `page_comments_adds` and `page_wall_posts` are deprecated, so you will have to look for some other metric to replace this info. `page_stories` maybe?

Alternatively you can use the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#analytics).

```
https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/insights/application_like_adds/day?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}&since=yesterday
```

Comment: Deprecated, you mean they will be removed/replaced soon?

Comment: Yep, they are marked as such in the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/#page_users)